# Enable USB 3.0 in Centos 7

Tags: centos-7, usb-3

¿Has anybody been able to use USB 3.0 in CentOS 7? I'm using kernel 5.0.1-1.el7.elrepo, and CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core).
I have an HP - Compaq HP ProDesk 400 G1 Mini,  the motherboard model is 198E from Hewlett Packard.

When I connect my external HDD to USB 2.0 port everything works ok. The external hard drive doesn't mount when I connect it to USB 3.0 port.

`lsusb` shows the following output

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Hope anybody can help me.

Comment: Please Edit the question to say your motherboard / CPU .  Please also say what tests you have run to determine if USB 3 is not working (how can you tell it's not working?).  Sometimes different ports will function differently, so try all of your USB ports (different controllers behind them on the motherboard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Had to disable "USB Debug" advanced option in my BIOS and everything is working now. 
Hope this helps anyone else having the same problem